# systemd on 15.04 won't log stdout of unit

Tags: 15.04, log, logging, systemd, stdout

I'm currently trying to make a systemd unit as a web server. Currently, my `foo.service` file looks as follows:

```
[Unit]
Description=The Foo Web Server

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/opt/foo/.cabal-sandbox/bin/foo

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The `foo` executable automatically logs all HTTP requests to stdout - this is well tested. However, when I view the logs with `journalctl -u foo`, I only get output like this:

```
...
May 06 17:46:57 localhost systemd[1]: Stopping The Foo Web Server...
May 06 17:46:57 localhost systemd[1]: Started Foo Web Server.
May 06 17:46:57 localhost systemd[1]: Starting The Foo Web Server...
May 06 17:47:08 localhost systemd[1]: Stopping The Foo Web Server...
May 06 17:47:08 localhost systemd[1]: Started The Foo Web Server.
May 06 17:47:08 localhost systemd[1]: Starting The Foo Web Server...
```

Could someone explain why it's not logging all stdout output? I looked briefly at [this previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20399/view-stdout-stderr-of-systemd-service), but it doesn't help - however it alluded to something along the lines of "...may not work for systems that don't use **full** systemd" - would this be the case for Ubuntu 15.04? Thank you in advance, any help with this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Make sure, your process is not buffering the output. I was having similar problem and it got resolved by disabling output buffering of my python script. As the number of log records produced was not high, it looked like there is no logging, but in fact, it had yet no chance, as all was still gathering in stdout output buffer.

Comment: Trying to fix this too. I have an impression that systemd does buffering. stdout is line-buffered in UNIX, but systemd does its own thing and buffers a lot more (in order to be fast but useless maybe).

Comment: I had the same problem and buffering with Python's print function was the problem!  Since I was using Python 3 I just used something like `print('Hello World!', flush=True)` and that did the trick!  Output started showing up in journalctl.

Comment: For python: an alternative to what @timbram suggested is putting `Environment=PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1` in your service file from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/608678/161268

Comment: What strange behavior. Far from ideal. One could even say not very platonic...

Answer (score 12):

In fact, buffering in UNIX depends on the context: when stdout is redirected to something interactive like a console - it is usually line-buffered, otherwise it is fully buffered.

Buffering may be changed inside the application using **setvbuf** library call.

But it can also be done with **stdbuf** command on launch:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/stdbuf -oL /opt/foo/.cabal-sandbox/bin/foo
```

(for line-buffered case)

Comment: This saved my day! Thank you very much. But I'm a bit confused that with `ExecStart=/my/foo/program`, why the stdout log is not flushed when the service is terminated, but completely disappears instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, the log messages are tagged with `stdbuf` instead of the actual program, but I can confirm that the command-line workaround does work. I'll probably need the library function to fix the tag.

Answer (score 0):

By default on *Ubuntu 15.04*, **systemd** journals are only volatile and kept in `/run/systemd/journal` and are lost at each reboot. To use **persistent** *systemd* journal, you need to create the `/var/log/journal` directory (and restart systemd-journald.service).

So, may be, `stdout` output is just redirected to `syslog` and not kept in *systemd* journal. For that, you may need to use a **persistent** *systemd* journal as explained above.

Have you checked `/var/log/syslog` for your `foo` log ?

Comment: I created the `/var/log/journal` as you mentioned, but I'm not seeing stdout of my systemd service anyway. in the `/var/log/syslog` I see neither it.